# Changing value of input box with Javascript defeats following call to focus method

Tags: javascript, jquery, setfocus

I have a web page that uses jQuery that has several input boxes.  The input boxes are set to auto-select the existing text (value property) when the click() event fires.  It was working great until I tried to pre-fill one of the input boxes from within the document ready() event.  If I do that, then despite calling the focus() method on the desired field, that field does not receive focus (cursor is not in the input box and the text is not auto-selected).  If I click on the field then the text does auto-select so that part still works, just not setting the focus.

I have included the Javascript code for the entire document ready event in case it's a bad synergy between the elements on the page.  Note the getSearchArguments() call simply takes the URL arguments and turns them into an associative array.  Here's the HTML for the E-mail address field I am trying to auto-focus/select:

```
<!-- E-mail Address -->
<div NAME="divEmailAddress" ID="divEmailAddress">
    <img NAME="imgEvernoteEmailAddress" ID="imgEvernoteEmailAddress" src="/images/evernote-mail-address.png" align="left" />
    <input type="text" NAME="emailAddress" ID="emailAddress" wrap="soft" style="margin-left:5px;width:600px;" title="Enter your Evernote E-mail address here" value="Enter your E-mail address" ></input>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that the focus() method still works after pre-filling an input box?

**UPDATE**: It turns out adding a new explicit call to select() after the focus() call solved the problem.  If someone could tell me why this is I'd appreciate it.

```
$(document).ready
(
    function() 
    {
        // Put jQuery related initialization code that must occur after the document is ready here.

        // Have all the edit boxes except the Tags edit box auto-select the current text upon entry.

        $("#editEvernoteTags").autoSuggest
        (
            data.items, 
            {
                selectedItemProp: "name", 
                searchObjProps: "name",
                startText: "Enter Evernote tags here...",
                /* See autoSuggest.css
                open: function(event, ui) 
                {
                    $(this).autoSuggest("widget").css
                    (
                        {
                            "width": 200
                        }
                    );
                }
                */
            } // data. items
        ); // $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest

        $("#emailAddress").onblur = checkEmailAddress;

        // $("#emailAddress").css('width', $("#editEvernoteTags").css('width') * 2);

        // Synchronize the control widths to the autoSuggest "as-selections" class element.
        var tagsWidth = $("ul.as-selections").width();
        $("#emailAddress").width(tagsWidth);
        $("#editComment").width(tagsWidth);

        // If an E-mail address was provided as a URL argument, put it in the E-mail address field.
        var urlEmailAddress = getSearchArguments().emailAddress;

        // >>> COMMENTING OUT THIS IF/ELSE BLOCK ALLOWS THE FOCUS() METHOD TO WORK.
        // value="Enter your E-mail address"
        if (urlEmailAddress)
            $("#emailAddress").val(urlEmailAddress);
        else
            $("#emailAddress").val("Enter your E-mail address");

        // E-mail address
        $('#emailAddress').click(function() 
        {
            $(this).select();
        });

        // Comment
        $('#editComment').click(function() 
        {
            $(this).select();
        });

        // Set focus to the E-mail field.
        $("#emailAddress").focus();
        // >>>> This is needed to initially select the text the first time
        //  if the pre-fill code above is used.
        $("#emailAddress").select();
    } // function() 
); // $(document).ready
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `$("#emailAddress").trigger('click');​​​​​​​​` instead of `$("#emailAddress").focus();`?

Comment: @caligula - I added the HTML snippet for the E-mail address and the DIV that owns it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set a focus handler. You've set a click handler. To trigger the event, use `.click()` and not `.focus()`.

```
$("#emailAddress").click();
```